# Countinuous Progress bar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme

I implemented a progress bar but I'm having problems.

The progress bar to complete should take 5 seconds. My problem is that the value is updated from second to second and I would like it to be continuous, without any kind of stops.

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-devextreme-sandbox-t66yne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html)

**HTML**

```
<dx-progress-bar
#progressBar
[showStatus]="false"
id="progress-bar-status"
[rtlEnabled]="true"
[class.complete]="progressBar.value == maxValue"
[min]="0"
[max]="maxValue"
[value]="maxValue - seconds"
>
</dx-progress-bar>
```

**.Ts**

```
 seconds = 5;
  maxValue = 5;
  intervalId: number;

  onButtonClick() {
    this.seconds = 5;
    this.intervalId = window.setInterval(() => this.timer(), 1000);
  }

  timer() {
    this.seconds--;
    if (this.seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
  }
```

**intended result**

[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_3)

Comment: For animations you should probably look at [`Window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: You need to change css transition..example: .dx-trackbar-range {
  transition: width 3s ease-in-out !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

The timer function is run every second, so running it every animation frame should work:

```
   seconds = 5;
   maxValue = 5;
   lastFrame = undefined;
   intervalId: number;
    
   onButtonClick() {
     this.seconds = 5;
     this.intervalId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.timer);
   }
    
   timer(time) {
     if (this.lastFrame == undefined) {
       this.lastFrame = time;
     }
     this.seconds -= (time - this.lastFrame);
     this.lastFrame = time;
     if (this.seconds > 0) {
       this.intervalId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.timer);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Every millisecond might be a bit much. Why not use `requestAnimationFrame()` instead?

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'll edit that in.

Comment: @OuterSoda Thanks for the reply. I'm having trouble implementing this for typescript. window.requestAnimationFrame(this.timer); I don't understand this line.

Comment: `window.requestAnimationFrame(this.timer);` runs the function `this.timer` on the next frame (next time the screen is redrawn). We call `this.timer` inside itself if the time remaining isn't 0 so that it will keep on running. We call it recursively so that we can exit out of it when the 5 seconds have passed.

Comment: Executing this, the declared variables give an error

Comment: Would you mind telling me how it gives an error, and what the error is?

Comment: If you use requestAnimationFrame, you just need to change this line ->     this.intervalId = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => window.setInterval(() => this.timer(), 1000)); within onButtonClick function

Comment: I have changed it to `this.intervalId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.timer);`.

Comment: so the timer() function needs a parameter. you can see it in my demo

Comment: It is automatically passed on as I am passing on the function itself, not an anonymous function that calls it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how `dx-trackbar-range` has transition `none` via inline styles. If you can't change it using component API, you can change it directly on your CSS file:

```
.dx-trackbar-range {
  transition: width 3s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

**working example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-devextreme-sandbox-4xzbua?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a simple solution, however the animation is not fully continuous.

Comment: You can play with the time, example: width 5s ease-in-out